# Assign default value to object if value is undefined

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm fetching data from an API, some fields are not required therefore undefined in the response object

I would like to assign a default empty value like `null` `''` `[]` to my object parameters if said fields are undefined in the response, so far here's what I have (I have more more fields to fetch but stopped at 5 for this example)

```
await axios.get('https://myurl.com').then( async (response) => {
    await Promise.all(response.data.map(async (commerce) => {

      let options = {
        // BASE INFO
        field1: commerce.field1[0].value,
        field2 : commerce.field2[0].value,
        field3 : commerce.field3[0].value,
        field4 : commerce.field4[0].value,
        field5 : commerce.field5[0].value,
      }

      const default_options = {
        // BASE INFO
        field1: null,
        field2 : '',
        field3 : '',
        field4 : [],
        field5 : null,
      }

      const commerceObj = Object.assign({}, default_options, options)
    }));

  });
```

I get an error if a field has no value for instance `commerce.field2[0] is undefined` because the API response doesn't include it, what I'm looking for would be an efficient way to do something like

`field2 : if(commerce.field2[0].value) { commerce.field2[0].value } else {''}`

Since I have a lot of fields I don't really wish to do have a lot of `if` in my code the only thing I could find that could help me is Object.assign() but it didn't help much

Comment: how about *optional chaining*, `commerce.field2[0]?.value`

Comment: `commerce.field2[0] ?? ""`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Conditional (ternary) operator.

Syntax: `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`

```
  let options = {
    field1: commerce.field1[0].value ? commerce.field1[0].value : '',
    ...
  }
```

Comment: You can even use [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to reduce the expression to `field1: commerce.field1[0].value ?? ''`

Comment: @jonatjano  That's the way I would do it these days, as one issue with this answer is that a numeric `0` is lost..  And apart from that it's shorter. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into using [`@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) this would allow you to do something such as:

```js
const field1 = commerce?.field1[0]?.value
```

You could also look into [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get):

```js
const field1 = _.get(commerce, 'field[0].value', null)
```

If not you'll have to do something a little more cluttered:

```js
commerce && commerce.field1 && commerce.field1.length
  ? commerce.field1[0].value
  : undefined
```

Comment: optional chaining is already implemented in every browser, there is no need for a babel plugin anymore (unless you're targeting IE)

Answer (score 1):

the idea you laking is to loop the first object and assign your default options dynamically

```
let options = {
        // BASE INFO
        field1: commerce.field1[0].value,
        field2 : commerce.field2[0].value,
        field3 : commerce.field3[0].value,
        field4 : commerce.field4[0].value,
        field5 : commerce.field5[0].value,
      }
const default_options = {
        // BASE INFO
        field1: null,
        field2 : '',
        field3 : '',
        field4 : [],
        field5 : null,
      }
for (const fieldKey in options) {
  if(!options[fieldKey])
    options[fieldKey] = default_options[fieldKey] // dynamically change it
}
```